# Convert any time zone date time into UTC date time using moment

Tags: angular, angular-material, momentjs

I have drop down for different time zones. All time zones i am loading from moment time zone, and adding to drop down.

```
timezone: any = {
nameAbbr: "America/New_York (EDT)",
name: "America/New_York",
abbr: 'EDT'
```

}

If i select any time zone from the drop down, date time should load related to that time zone and later need to converted to UTC.

Here is the code i am trying to convert selected time zone to UTC.

```
moment(date).tz(timezone.name).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss')
```

Default selected time zone is 'America/New_York'. It's converting to UTC correctly for default selected time zone.

But if i change time zone to 'Asia/Kolkata', It's giving last selected time zone (America/New_York) UTC date time only.

Can any one look into this issue?

HTML code is

```
<mat-form-field class="auto-complete-full-width">
  <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="timeZoneControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let timezone of filteredOptions | async" [value]="timezone.nameAbbr" (onSelectionChange)="onChangeTimezone(timezone)">
      {{ timezone.nameAbbr }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Have you considered using the built in https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe ?

Comment: @Sekhar can you post HTML of the dropdown?

Comment: In my case, we have to send date time to api. so DatePipe is not required.